# How to achieve sliding animation from top to bottom in Android(need to push the content below as this animation happens)?

Tags: android, android-animation

My layout will have the following things:

1. I have a title (a Linear Layout)
2. The first content block (a relative layout which is in gone state for now)
3. The second content block (again a relative layout which is visible)

I need to animate the first content block from top to bottom while pushing the second content block below in the same phase the first content block is moving.

I tried so many methods. In all those things second content block is visble at its place and then first content block is moving upto its top. Kindly give me some suggestions.

Comment: Can you share any gif or video reference for required animation? Only text not giving idea of proper animation.

Comment: you should manually calculate the bounds and move the both together from its intersection points

Comment: Without accessing second content, is it possible to push both only with the help of first content itself?

Comment: @Manish Dubey I'm really sorry Manish. I dont have any video reference with me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give id to your layouts and then create animation.

Here is the sample code.

```
public void SlideToAbove() {
        Animation slide = null;
        slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -2.0f);

        slide.setDuration(400);
        slide.setFillAfter(true);
        slide.setFillEnabled(true);
        rl_footer.startAnimation(slide);

        slide.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                rl_footer.clearAnimation();

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 200);
                // lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
                lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
                rl_footer.setLayoutParams(lp);

            }

        });

    }

    public void SlideToDown() {
        Animation slide = null;
        slide = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1.0f);

        slide.setDuration(400);
        slide.setFillAfter(true);
        slide.setFillEnabled(true);
        rl_footer.startAnimation(slide);

        slide.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                rl_footer.clearAnimation();

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 70);
                // lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
                lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
                rl_footer.setLayoutParams(lp);

            }

        });

    }
```

where rl_footer and header are the id's of layout which are visible to user. You can call it like

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    iv_header.setImageResource(R.drawable.android);
                    iv_header.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 0);
                    SlideToAbove();

                }
            });
```

on your button click or touch

Regards

Comment: The view i'm going to animate will be re used.It will be in gone state in the beginning. I need to animate it from top to bottom without using any other view's id or reference(Since it is reused we are planning to separate it).

Comment: yeah, you need to tweak this code a little to suit your needs.